# Angular Filtering a List with Toggle

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my app, I'm trying to filter a list using toggle. I want the toggle to filter the list depending on its `ContactStateType`. Right now, when I slide the toggle, it filters the whole list and shows an empty list or, it shows the whole list. It doesn't filter it at all. What should I add to my code to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
                <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isActive" (change)="contactFilter()" class="mr-8">
                    {{isActive ? 'Silindi' : 'Aktif'}}</mat-slide-toggle>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end" class="mat-elevation-z4 responsive-grid">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="stock-table pb-4">
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="CompanyName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Firma Adı</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.CompanyName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="ContactName">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ad-Soyad</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.ContactName}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="InternalPhone">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Dahili</th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.InternalPhone}} </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IContact>;
isActive: boolean = true;
contactFilter() {
  this._adminService
      .getContactList()
      .then((response: IContact[]) => {
          if (this.isActive) {
              response = response.filter((x) => x.ContactStateType == 1);
          }

          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>
              this.filterPredicate(data, filter);
      });
}
  filterPredicate(data: IContact, filter: string) {
let searchText = '';
if (data.CompanyName) { searchText += (data.CompanyName as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr'); }
if (data.ContactName) { searchText += (data.ContactName as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr'); }
if (data.InternalPhone) { searchText += (data.InternalPhone as any); }
if (data.MobilePhone) { searchText += (data.MobilePhone as any); }
if (data.Fax) { searchText += (data.Fax as any); }
if (data.Address) { searchText += (data.Address as any); }
if (data.EMail) { searchText += (data.EMail as any); }
if (data.WebSite) { searchText += (data.WebSite as any); }
if (data.SectorType) { searchText += (data.SectorType as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr'); }
if (data.Notes) { searchText += (data.Notes as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr'); }
return searchText.indexOf(filter) >= 0;
```

}

Comment: Code-wise this doesn't look wrong, altough i'd question re-fetching everytime this toggle is changed. What's the data looking like? maybe there just are no entries with ContactStateType == 1?

Comment: also, could you add the `this.filterPredicate` method to the code example?

Comment: I added it. And checked it in the network, it does have entries with ContactStateType ==1